# Jquery .focus().select() not working on first interaction

Tags: jquery

I am working on a pretty simple solution where I want a enter press to cause focus on the object next to it.

Console logging nextInput shows the correct input field, and the code is "working", if you press enter twice, it will actually go to the object, but it is not going to the object on the first enter press

I hope someone might be able to explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

```
_onKeydown(ev) {
        if (ev.keyCode === 13) {
            ev.preventDefault();

            var nextInput = this.$el.parents().find("input.o_input").not(this.$el).not(".ui-autocomplete-input");
            nextInput.focus().select();
        }
```

Comment: Please see [mcve] - please provide a *complete* snippet that demonstrates the issue.  eg that is `this.$el`?  What debugging have you done to determine if `nextInput` is the correct input (rather than assume focus/select is incorrect)?   focus.select works fine when nextInput is correct: https://jsfiddle.net/2thk1uam/1/ and using parents().find() https://jsfiddle.net/2thk1uam/2/

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me were to change .focus to .click and it worked :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).